# Add HTML but not in text mode of TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a big text and like to highlight words that are trademarks. So within this big CDATA node I need to grab for multiple words like "ACME Soda Chips" and make them red.
currently I do something like this in a TinyMCE plugin:

```
// almost ...
var foo = editor.getContent();
foo.replace('ACME Soda Chips', '<span class="douh">ACME Soda Chips</span>');
editor.setContent(foo);
```

My problem now is, that such HTML is displayed in Text-Mode (where you see the content as plain HTML) and also submitted therefor stored to the database.

But what I like to have is:

- Highlight a word in the visual mode
- Do not store my surrounding span somehow
- Optional: Do not show that I used a span and CSS-class to highlight things.

Hint:

- I may completely do this wrong - please help.
- I read some other plugins and honestly I don't understand what they do.
- Imagine the whole text as one single big CDATA part but I like to highlight a specific set out of it.

Comment: you can preprocess the tinymce editor content before sending it to the backend and remove your inserted span tags

Comment: Thanks @Thariama, this is a hint. How do I remove the unwanted things from the text view? And more important: Is there a "correct" way to add a node to the preview / mce view?

Comment: It depends on how you send your tinymce content to the server. It is possible to clean your content on the client or the server side. The way you insert your custom nodes is fine.